# MySQL query not working when added date comparison

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The query works fine if the date the last condition from the WHERE clause is removed (settlement_Date) 
I have also tried LIKE operator, BETWEEN Condition but none of them prosuced the result
The SETTLEMENT_DATE Column is of datetime type with format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
I have also tried

```
SETTLEMENT_DATE BETWEEN "2010-04-01 00:00:00" AND "2010-04-01 23:59:59"
```

And I want the query to shows the results of a particular date

```
SELECT date_format(SETTLEMENT_DATE,"%H:%i") AS "TIME",
SUM(CASE WHEN CORPORATE_ID=1328727040 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "TOTAL",
SUM(CASE WHEN CORPORATE_ID=1328727040 AND ( QUOTA_CODE=0 OR QUOTA_CODE =1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Non-Tatkal",
SUM(CASE WHEN CORPORATE_ID=1328727040 AND QUOTA_CODE=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Tatkal"
FROM ticket
WHERE PNR_NUMBER!="0"
AND CURRENT_RES_STATUS NOT IN (9,10,11,16)
AND date(SETTLEMENT_DATE) = str_to_date('01-04-2014', '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY date_format(SETTLEMENT_DATE,"%H:%i")
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: What do you want now, 2014 or 2010 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

applying a date() function to your column can not utilize a possible index.  I have typically found the following type of condition works well with dates...

```
SETTLEMENT_DATE >= '2010-04-01' 
AND SETTLEMENT_DATE < '2010-04-02'
```

This way, you leave the date-based field alone, and the >= starting date is obvious, but the second being LESS than the following day at midnight is the same as your 2010-04-01 at 11:59:59pm but does not include 2010-04-02.

Comment: can this work with condition like this
settlement_date >= date1 AND settlement_date < date1+1

Comment: I've got it using date_add() 
Thanks for the help

Comment: @SunnyArora, as long as the concept works... regardless of a fixed string or a date_add().  Dealing with date AND time components, this helps eliminate any ambiguity.  Also adjusted to single-quotes around dates, not double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
str_to_date('01-04-2014', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

when you run it like:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2014', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

It gives:

```
'2001-04-20'
```

But your dates are in the range: `"2010-04-01 00:00:00" AND "2010-04-01 23:59:59"`

Comment: but for comparison in where clause I have applied date() on the Settlement_date Column so it would produce only date for comparison